# how to find Bitnami hadoop appliance password?

Tags: passwords, bitnami, appliance

I installed bitnami hadoop that is here

https://bitnami.com/stack/hadoop/virtual-machine#credentials

How do I find the root password?

Comment: Hi Tarek, the credentials are stored in a file present into the bitnami's home directory

"cat /home/bitnami/bitnami_credentials"

Comment: The file says "default user " user
and a password

but the user "user does not exist

"

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. I just launched a fresh Bitnami Hadoop VM and could log in to the application using "user" as username and the generated random password. Please review you are using the correct credentials when accessing the app.